# how to sum an array in java using templates in generic without getting the bad operand type erroe

Tags: java

```
public class sum_array_temp
{

   public static <E> void printArray(E[] Array) 
   {
       E sum = Array[0];
       for(int i=0; i<Array.length; i++)
       {
           sum=sum+Array[i];
       }
       /*for(E element : inputArray) {
         System.out.printf("%s ", element);
       }*/
       System.out.println(sum);
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) 
   {   
      Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      Double[] doubleArray = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4 };      
      printArray(intArray);      
      printArray(doubleArray);      
   }
}
```

I want to print the sum of array using template its showing bad operand error on (+) operator.

Comment: Why is that method generic? What do you expect to use as concrete types?

Comment: Plus (`+`) is not defined for generic types, ie. `E`, only for scalar numeric types.

Comment: Have your tried: http://vbwithsuman.blogspot.com/p/working-with-control-array.html. It may provide with help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of `printArray()` does not say anything about `E`. It can be any type and `+` is only defined for scalar numeric types. If you require `E` to be a sub-class of `Number` you can do most of what you want to do. For example,

```
public static <E extends Number> void printArraySum(E[] array)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (E elt : array)
    {
        sum += elt.doubleValue();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

It's not ideal though as the sum is always a `double` even for `Integer` arrays.